# How to retain headers for all the pages of an exported pdf in php?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, header

I am exporting  data from php page to pdf 
when the datas exceeed the page limit the header is not available for the consecutive pages
function where i call the export to pdf is
function changeDetails()
    {
                $bType = $this->input->post('textvalue');

```
                  if($bType == "pdf")
        {
            $this->load->library('table');
            $this->load->plugin('to_pdf');
            $data['countrytoword'] = $this->AddEditmodel1->export();
            $this->table->set_heading('Country','State','Town','Name');
            $out =  $this->table->generate($data['countrytoword']);
            $html = $this->load->view( 'newpdf',$data, true);
            pdf_create($html, $cur_date);
        }
    }
```

This is my view page from which i export data to pdf

 
    
        
            Name
        
        
            Country
        
        
            State
        
        
            Town

```
</tr>
```

Here I am getting the result as

> **page:1**
>
> `Name`      `country`      `State`   `Town`
>                  udaya             india         Tamilnadu      kovai
>                  chandru          srilanka      columbo       aaaaa
>
> **page:2**
>                  vivek      england       gggkj           gjgjkj

in the page 2 i dont get the headers name, country ,state and town

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help if you specifiy the PDF library you are using. I know that [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) supports spanning of tables across pages and it will repeat the table headers on every page, so you might check it out.

Check example 48 on the following page to see an example of table headers :
http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf_examples

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old, rather vague question, but in case others have this problem as I did:

It of course depends on the library, but using mPDF, table headers will repeats on multiple pages if you wrap your header and body in  and  tags:

```
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Head 1</th>
     <th>Head 2</th>
     <th>Head 3</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
    </tr>    
    etc...  
   </tbody>
  </table>
```